# Vue-Router only works on some routes

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

My vue-router routes the URL on all menu buttons correctly, but does not show each Vue component properly. A demonstration can be found [here](https://eankeen.github.io/appliance-manager/#/).

Inside of my HTML (I am using Vuefy)

```
<div class="navbar-start">
        <a class="navbar-item">
          <router-link to="/" class="router-link">  // <-- THIS WORKS
          Home
        </router-link>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-item">
          <router-link to="/items" class="router-link">  // <-- THIS WORKS
          My Products
        </router-link>
        </a>
      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
          <a class="navbar-link">
            <router-link to="/information" class="router-link">  // <-- DOES NOT WORK
            Info
            </router-link>
          </a>
        <div class="navbar-dropdown is-boxed">
          <a class="navbar-item">
            <router-link to="/about" class="router-link">  // <-- THIS WORKS
            About
            </router-link>
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item">
            <router-link to="/terms" class="router-link">  // <-- DOES NOT WORK
            Terms
          </router-link>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My router.js file is set up the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import('./views/About.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/new',
      name: 'create-item',
      component: () => import('./views/CreateItem.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/items',
      name: 'my-items',
      component: () => import('./views/MyItems.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/signin',
      name: 'sign-in',
      components: () => import('./views/SignIn.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/terms',
      name: 'terms',
      components: () => import('./views/Terms.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/information',
      name: 'info',
      components: () => import('./views/Info.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

Additionally, my App.vue file shows the router-view properly, along with the menu.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <Menu/>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    import Menu from '@/components/Menu.vue'

    export default {
      components: {
        Menu
      }
    }
</script>
```

The following is a photograph of my navigation. To repeat, clicking on 'info' and 'terms' (submenu of info) do not load their respective Vue components, but *does* change the URL.
[image]

I triple-checked my syntax and checked the documentation, but could not seem to find my error. The platform at which my code is hosted at can be found [here](https://github.com/EanKeen/appliance-manager/tree/1dc1a35e20830f419200c9fde35074661ea003da). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, Edwin.

Comment: I'm curious why the `<router-link>` elements are wrapped in anchor tags. Is that a Vuefy or Bulma thing?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter is right, on render its going to nest links which is most likely the issue, instead just put `navbar-link` class on the `router-link` and remove the outer anchor tags, also the drop down is going to fire off the `information` link, when the user might want `about`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I spelled 'component' instead of 'components' several times in my routes.js file.